# Two monotone functions have the same derivative when both differentiable, and the same discontinuities. Must they differ by a constant?

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, measure-theory

Suppose $f: [0,1]\to [0,1]$ and $g: [0,1]\to [0,1]$ both satisfy the following:

(1) They are both weakly increasing.

(2) They are discontinuous at the same set of points. Moreover, if $f$ and $g$ are discontinuous at $x$, then $$\lim_{z\rightarrow x^{+}}f(z)-\lim_{z\rightarrow x^{-}}f(z)=\lim_{z\rightarrow x^{+}}g(z)-\lim_{z\rightarrow x^{-}}g(z)$$

(3) If $f$ and $g$ are both differentiable at $x$, then $f'(x)=g'(x)$.

Is it true that for any $x$ and $z$ where $f$ and $g$ are continuous, $f(x)-g(x)=f(z)-g(z)$?

Comment: What means *weakly* increasing? Non-decreasing?

Comment: I am thinking about the Cantor function.

Comment: I imagine it can be easily proved If there is a finite number of jump discontinuity and the two functions are differentiable in each interval not containing the discontinuities

Comment: Let $f$ be the Cantor function and $g$ be a constant function. Then what?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Cantor function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_function) $f$ and $f_0$, the always vanishing map are both continuous and non-decreasing. Therefore:

1. Is satisfied
2. Is also satisfied as both $f$ and $f_0$ doesn't have discontinuity points.
3. Differentiability is the tricky point. $f$ is differentiable on $[0,1] \setminus C$ where $C$ is the Cantor set, and not differentiable elsewhere. See [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/851850/differentiability-of-the-cantor-function) for a reference. Moreover $f^\prime(x) = 0$ for $x \in [0,1] \setminus C$ which is also the case for $f_0$. Therefore point (3) is also satisfied.

However $f(0)=f_0(0)=0$ while $f(1)=1 \neq 0 =f_0(1)$.