Suppose $f:[a,b]\to \mathbb{R}$ is a continuous semi-differentiable function. Is it true that $f$ is differentiable outside a countable set?
Let $f:[a,b] \to \mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function on $[a,b]$ such that there exists $f_{+}'(x) \in \mathbb{R}, (\forall) x \in [a,b)$. Is it true that there exists a countable set $D \subset [a,b]$ such that $f$ is differentiable on $(a,b) \setminus D$?
My guess is that this is not true and i have to build a counter-example around a cantor set, or maybe something non-measurable because the set of points where $f$ is differentiable is a measurable set when $f$ is a continuous function. How can i construct such an example?

$f'(x) \in \mathbb R$ cannot be used as  a synonym for $f$ is differentiable at $x$.

I don't have a good intuition for this kind of functions. For lipschitz functions one can get arbitrary null sets (see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2444065/does-lipschitz-continuous-function-only-has-a-countable-non-differentiable-point). Now one could try to check whether the construction in that paper also yields something relevant for the semi-differentiable case (or at least it might give you an idea how to potentially build some counterexample).

Maybe, the Cantor function also yields a counterexample. It is continuous, but non-differentiable for all points in the Cantor set. Though I do not know whether it is semi-differentiable.

Well, actually the Cantor function does not work, as it is not semi-differentiable (see here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/851850/differentiability-of-the-cantor-function). Not a great guess on my part.

Does $f'(x+0)$ mean the limit of $f'(y)$ as $y$ approaches $x$ on the right, or does $f'(x+0)$ mean the right derivative of $f'(y)$ at $y=x$?

@DaveL.Renfro I apologize for the misunderstanding, I meant there exists
$$\lim_{h\to 0^+} \dfrac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h} \in \mathbb{R},$$ i.e the right derivative.

Look over my answer to [Real-valued function of one variable which is continuous on $[a,b]$ and semi-differentiable on $a,b)$? I don't have time now to locate (and possibly specialize to a less precise result) in that answer what you are looking for, but surely it's in that answer somewhere. (Right now I'm at my computer for something else, and only for a few minutes.) And I see that "semi-differentiable" is used there also, but note this was 12 years ago!

I've finished what I came to my desk to take care of (unrelated to Stack Exchange stuff), and it seems taking less than a minute (maybe just a few seconds) looking at my 2012 answer would have been enough to answer your question (the conjecture is TRUE). Related is this mathoverflow answer.
